# BBedit, deleting different text between two letter

Tags: xml, string, bbedit

hi to all i ve a lot of line (like 6000) with this format:

```
<item component="ComponentInfo{com.Fraom.KiwiUI/com.Fraom.KiwiUI.LicenseActivity}" drawable="kiwi_ui"/>
```

and i need to delete from all line the text between Componentinfo to /
the the result would be this:

```
<item component="com.Fraom.NucleoUI.LicenseActivity}" drawable="flatdroid"/>
```

any way for do this automatically ?
Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

Open the BBEdit find window, click the "Grep" checkbox and work on your regular expression in the find box until it consistently finds exactly what you want to replace.  Then type the replacement in the replace box (or leave to replace box empty to just delete the found strings) and click replace all (or replace & find).  In this case, you would use something like this in your find box:

```
ComponentInfo.*?/
```

and use an empty replace box.

If you need more information about regular expressions, search for "regex tutorial".  Heads up - regex is a very complex topic.